# Value of programmatically added checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have been searching for the solution for this for a while so I hope I can get some help now. I am attempting to figure out whether a programmatically added checkbox is checked using jquery. The HTML code of the checkbox is below:

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" name='ismanual' id='ismanual' class="checkbox">
</td>
```

And I am doing it using the following jquery code:

```
var ismanual = document.getElementById("ismanual").val();
```

I have attempted using #ismanual as the selector, but that didn't help. Any idea where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Don't confuse native DOM elements with jQuery objects. `.val()` is a jQuery method, so it only works on jQuery objects - also, it is not the right tool for checking whether a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `document.getElementById("ismanual")` you should use `.checked` instead of `.val()`...

```
var ismanual = document.getElementById("ismanual").checked;
```

For jQuery use...

```
var ismanual = $("#ismanual").is(':checked')
```

Comment: @JeroenMoons he is confused, he heard all the cool kids are using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. This is correct. I mixed up Javascript and jQuery in my question. Doh!
Another issue was that I include a .js file, which was cached so my changes weren't reflected. Do you know how I can avoid this caching?

Comment: @Peta, obviously forcing a refresh of the page in your browser will do it... otherwise you could look at putting a random value as part of the `src` request, but that requires the link to be generated via javascript, and means the file would be downloaded every single time. You could also put the file within a directory called something like `/v1/myscript.js` and increase the value each time you change something, but that can become confusing if you're not careful

Comment: Found a solution to it here: http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache
As you mentioned it will however download the file each time a change is made. I think I will use the versioning solution when pushing to production

Answer (score 3):

Where you have gone wrong: if you want to use val(), you need to use it on a jQuery object. getElementById() gives you a DOM element but not a jQuery object. To get a jQuery object you need to find the element using a jQuery selector like this:

```
jQuery('#ismanual')
```

You can then use jQuery's [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function on that object:

```
var isManual = jQuery('#ismanual').is(':checked');
```

Comment: You can also use `.prop()` to get the original DOM property.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is a `jQuery` function. It will not work with DOM style element selection.

To get value using `.getElementById()`, you must use `.checked` like,

`var ismanual = document.getElementById("ismanual").checked;`

`.val()` will work when you are selecting the element using `jQuery` like,

```
$("#ismanual").val();
```